# Pytest ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pytest, python-import

Even for as long as I've worked in Python, I still occasionally run into issues with my package structure.

I'm trying to run `$ pipenv run pytest` from the root of the directory structure below (i.e. `..` above src/)

```
src/
   physics/
      __init__.py
      pathing.py
   road/
      tests/
          __init__.py
          test_traffic.py
      __init__.py
      traffic.py
   __init__.py
   main.py
```

traffic.py:

```
    from physics import pathing

    class Intersection():
        ...

    class Vehicle():
        ...
```

test_traffic.py

```
    from src.road.traffic import Intersection, Vehicle

    def test_intersection():
        ...
```

However, I get hit with:

```
======================================================================= ERRORS ========================================================================
___________________________________________________ ERROR collecting src/road/tests/test_traffic.py ___________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/justian/scripts/py-traffic-sim/src/road/tests/test_traffic.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
src/road/tests/test_traffic.py:1: in <module>
    from src.road.traffic import Intersection, Vehicle
src/road/traffic.py:13: in <module>
    from physics import pathing
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'physics'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================================================================== 1 error in 0.38s ===================================================================
```

It looks like I'm misunderstanding how pytest is importing my modules or misunderstanding how my modules are referencing one another. Both `$ pipenv run pytest` and `$ pipenv run python -m pytest` produce the same result.

How can I properly import `Intersection` and `Vehicle` into test_traffic.py?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `__init__.py` file from `src`.

e.g.

```
src/
   physics/
      __init__.py
      pathing.py
   road/
      tests/
          __init__.py
          test_traffic.py
      __init__.py
      traffic.py
   __init__.py    # Remove this one
   main.py
```

Comment: So this works for testing if I remove `src/__init__.py` and change the import in test_traffic.py to `from road.traffic import Intersection, Vehicle`, but how then do I run my project with pipenv?

`$ pipenv run src/main.py` produces: `Error: the command src/main.py could not be found within PATH or Pipfile's [scripts].`

Comment: Note there are also other files in src/ other than main.py that I didn't list prior to better scope the question.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the command in my terminal. I believe `pipenv run python src/main.py` works. Appreciate the help!