# filestructure for pytest, ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, pytest

How do I have to arrange my files so `python -m pytest` finds the classes in them?

---

I have the following strucutre (following the [pytest docs convention](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code)) and several stackoverflow posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59834619/pytest-modulenotfounderror) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62155663/5934316) for example):

```
├─ testapp
│   ├─ module
│   │   ├─ __init__.py
│   │   ├─ app.py
│   ├─ test
│   │   ├─ test_app.py
```

The files contain the following:

```py
# __init__.py

from .app import App
```

```py
# app.py

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b
```

```py
# test_app.py

import sys
import pytest

# sys.path.insert(0, '../') # doesn't make any difference
# sys.path.insert(0, '../module') # doesn't make any difference
# print(sys.path) # shows that testapp/ is in the path no matter if the two lines above are included or not

import module.App # doesn't work

class TestApp:
    def test_add():
        app = module.App()
        assert app.add(1, 2) == 3
```

When I run `python -m pytest` in the `testapp/` (it even sais it is ececuted with the root on `testapp/`) I get the error: *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module.App'*.

I tried `module.app.App` with and without removing the code in the `__init__.py`. I tried inserting `.` and `..` and `../module` to the path before importing. I tried to add `__init__.py`s in the `testapp/` and/or in the `testapp/test`. I tried adding a [`conftest.py`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/pythonpath.html#standalone-test-modules-conftest-py-files). Nothing works. But this is the "Good Integration Practices" ([cite from pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#good-integration-practices)) so this should be working.

What am I doing wrong? What do I have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module.App'`.

You get the error that there's no module `module.App` because `module.App` is not a module, it's a class.

Just `import module` and it'll work fine using `python -mpytest`. You'll need a `conftest.py` at the root of the directory iff you also want a direct `pytest` (without `python -m`) to work, [as documented](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/pythonpath.html#invoking-pytest-versus-python-m-pytest).

Comment: Thank you so much. That was a stupid mistake. It takes two more minuts until I can accpet your answer. But I will, it fixed my problem.