# Conda + Pytest ModuleNotFoundError for implemented file

Tags: python, anaconda, pytest

The accepted answer from the following have not resolved my issue:

- [Pytest ModuleNotFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59834619/pytest-modulenotfounderror)
- [ModuleNotFoundError issue for pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605830/modulenotfounderror-issue-for-pytest)

I am developing on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Structure

- TopLevel

  - task

    - **init**.py
    - file1.py
    - main.py
  - tests

    - **init**.py
    - testFile.py

Code that causes the error is inside of testFile.py

- from task.file1 import Class

Error message:

- ModuleNotFoundError: No module names 'Class'

I realize it has to do with python searching only the test directory and I followed what this answer suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61806535/14179793
It reveals that the task/ directory is not being searched but even when I implement what is suggested it still does not work.

Comment: Please also check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada).

Comment: How about `from task.file1 import Class`?

Comment: @Jzbach So that is actually how I have it I just left it out. I have updated the question.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen #1 of the question you linked does not resolve the issue and I am not sure how to do #2. I am running pytest from the TopLevel and I have to try to keep it that way.

Comment: How are you running the tests? Are you using the command line (i.e. `python -m pytest [...]`) or some IDE like PyCharm? If the command line, which command are you issuing?

Comment: @Jzbach I am using the terminal inside of PyCharm. The command I use is `pytest tests`. Interestingly this worked fine on the Windows machine i was using but not on Ubuntu but I have to use Ubuntu now.

Comment: PyCharm already has this preconfigured testing configs. If you go to Run>Edit Configurations and add a new configuration, you can scroll down and see "Pytest" under "Python Tests". There you can select your target *and put the working directory as your TopLevel*. If you're lost let me know and I'll try to make some screenshots

Comment: @Jzbach Okay, I am pretty sure I did it correctly. I created a run configuration with the target /.../testFile.py and working directory TopLevel but I get the same error. I will note that these tests will be run from the command line in a GitHub action so even if this were to work it wouldn't be a final solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226330/discussion-between-jzbach-and-michael).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen please don't hesitate to vote a dupe next time :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have found a solution working from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10253916/14179793

The proposed solution did not work:
`sys.path.insert(0, myPath + '/../')`
but the following did:
`sys.path.insert(0, myPath + '/../task')`

I did not realize the difference in directory structure.